# django __date returns None in MySQL while it returns date object in Sqlite3

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, datetime

Simple question:

`Model.objects.values('some_datetime_field__date',)`

returns the correct values of dates with sqlite, but it returns Nones in MySQL 5.7

The model is like:

```
class Inbound(models.Model):
    effective_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=True)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    # other fields.
```

I was using code below to count the number by dates(date only, not datetime)

```
daily_changes = Inbound.objects.all().values('effective_date__date')\
  .annotate(total_change=Sum('number'))
```

It worked fine with sqlite3 but fails on MYSQL
After debugging it was because `Inbound.objects.values('effective_date__date')` just returns Nones in Mysql

Comment: Does `some_datetime_field__date` exist and does it have a value

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry for the bad format first. But this problem is very ridiculous and it really makes me mad. `some_datetime_field` have correct value of datetime, but `some_datetime_field__date` just returns None. It works fine in sqlite3 but gives error on mysql.

Comment: Well we have better see the schema and an idea of the data content

Comment: ___Major Point___ Your original question did not mention `sqlite` or `mysql` Please think about the question before posting it

Answer (score -1):

This is the Django **values()** method declaration :

```
values(*fields, **expressions)
```

As you can see `some_datetime_field` of your model is a field where `some_datetime_field__date` is not a field of your model.

Comment: ```Model.objects.values('some_datetime_field__date',) ``` works fine witiih sqlite3